# mysql query - grouping by combined ids

Tags: php, mysql, database

Here's the table that I'm working with:

```
CREATE TABLE `index` (
 `wid` int(7) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `pid` int(7) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `value` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 UNIQUE KEY `wid` (`wid`,`pid`),
 KEY `pid` (`pid`),
 KEY `value` (`value`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

I have integer values of "pid" matching various "wid" that are only unique together.

For instance, I have:

```
pid - wid - value
 1  -  5  -  7
 1  -  6  -  5
 1  -  7  -  9
 2  -  5  -  2
 2  -  8  -  4
 3  -  8  -  8
 3  -  7  -  12
 4  -  5  -  5
 .. -  .. -  ..
```

Now let's assume I want to get PID where WID matches 5 and 7 order by the highest sum of VALUE.

So PID 1 matches 2 WID's (5,7) whose sum VALUE is 16 (7 + 9).
And PID 2 matches only 1 WID (5) whose sum VALUE is 2.
And PID 3 matches WID (7) whose sum VALUE is 12.

I need to construct the query that does this and sorts by SUM VALUE descending.

Such as:

```
SELECT
    index.pid, SUM(index.value) TotalSum
FROM index
WHERE
    index.wid = 5 or index.wid = 7
GROUP BY UNIQUE(index.pid)
ORDER BY TotalSum DESC
```

I know this query is incorrect but I'm trying to show what I'm trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to accomplish is approx correct.

Try below :

```
SELECT index.pid, SUM(index.value) TotalSum
FROM index
WHERE (wid = 5 or wid = 7)   //if you want only from wid 5,7 elase no need for it
GROUP BY index.pid
ORDER BY TotalSum DESC
```

Comment: oh i guess the SUM operation really does exist lol. thanks that halped me solve it!